# my custom exception class do not find CI_Exception class in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, exception

I build a custom class in system/core classes called BL_Exceptions.php. But when I use the custom class, it says cannot find the BL_Exception class.

```
    if( $type == 'customer') {
            $this->template->load('customer_new');

    }else{
            throw new BL_Exceptions(10001);
    }
```

Comment: Umm, it needs to be in `application/core` and you need to ensure your custom prefix is set to BL instead of MY in your config. Can you try that and see if it works?

Comment: oopz.. I really didn't know there are two core folders. Thnks @Tim. I'll try now.

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: @Priyanga Yes, CI is structured in a way that you'd seldom need to change or add _anything_ in `system/`, which really simplifies upgrading CI when new releases come out. You can basically just replace the `system/` directory with the new one and be done with it (in most cases). Barring a rare case where you need to change something in the core that you can't with hooks or overloading, everything that you work on should be in `application/`.